# Transform XLM to Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

I'm working with a client's api.

I'm making the following call via python:

```
import requests
# SOAP request URL
url = "https://url.com"
  
# structured XML
payload = """
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:util="http://url.com/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <util:localidadesListar>
    <usuario>user</usuario>
    <clave>password</clave>
   </util:localidadesListar>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> 
"""

# headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
}


# POST request
response = requests.request("POST", url, data = payload , headers = headers, verify = False)
```

This give me a model.Response module. In response variable exist the "text" atributte where the dataframe i need is located.

If i run the next code, i recieved this:

```
x = response.text
print(x)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <ns2:localidadesListarResponse xmlns:ns2="http://url.com/"> 
   <return>

&lt;Respuesta&gt;&lt;Estado&gt;OK&lt;/Estado&gt;&lt;Mensajes&gt;&lt;/Mensajes&gt;&lt;ItemsLocalidades&gt;&lt;ItemLocalidad&gt;
&lt;CodigoLocalidad&gt;1&lt;/CodigoLocalidad&gt;
&lt;DescripcionLocalidad&gt;IQUIQUE&lt;/DescripcionLocalidad&gt;
&lt;AbreviaturaLocalidad&gt;&lt;/AbreviaturaLocalidad&gt;
&lt;DepartamentoLocalidad&gt;1&lt;/DepartamentoLocalidad&gt;
&lt;/ItemLocalidad&gt;&lt;ItemLocalidad&gt; 

   </return>
  </ns2:localidadesListarResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can i convert that text into a dataframe?

Comment: The embedded xml inside <return> is not well formed xml. Provid a valid example, please.

Answer (score 0):

If your inner xml result is well formed like in my example, you can do something like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import html
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse("Soap1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

inner_string = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Respuesta>
  <Estado>OK</Estado>
  <Mensajes></Mensajes>
  <ItemsLocalidades>
    <ItemLocalidad>
      <CodigoLocalidad>1</CodigoLocalidad>
      <DescripcionLocalidad>IQUIQUE</DescripcionLocalidad>
      <AbreviaturaLocalidad></AbreviaturaLocalidad>
      <DepartamentoLocalidad>1</DepartamentoLocalidad>
    </ItemLocalidad>
    <ItemLocalidad>
      <CodigoLocalidad>2</CodigoLocalidad>
      <DescripcionLocalidad>IQUIQUE2</DescripcionLocalidad>
      <AbreviaturaLocalidad>Something</AbreviaturaLocalidad>
      <DepartamentoLocalidad>2</DepartamentoLocalidad>
    </ItemLocalidad>
  </ItemsLocalidades>
</Respuesta>"""


columns = ["estado", "mensajes", "codigoLocalidad", "descripcionLocalidad", "abreviaturaLocalidad", "departamentoLocalidad"]
for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag == "return":
        s = elem.text.strip()
        inner_xml = html.unescape(s)
        #print(repr(s))
        inner_root = ET.fromstring(s)
        
        req_list = []
        for req in inner_root.iter('Respuesta'):
            estado = req.find('Estado').text
            mensajes = req.find('Mensajes').text
            itemsLocalidades = req.findall('./ItemsLocalidades/')
            for itemsLocalidade in itemsLocalidades:
                codigoLocalidad = itemsLocalidade.find('CodigoLocalidad').text
                descripcionLocalidad = itemsLocalidade.find('DescripcionLocalidad').text
                abreviaturaLocalidad = itemsLocalidade.find('AbreviaturaLocalidad').text
                departamentoLocalidad = itemsLocalidade.find('DepartamentoLocalidad').text
                repelem = [estado, mensajes, codigoLocalidad, descripcionLocalidad, abreviaturaLocalidad, departamentoLocalidad]
                req_list.append(repelem)
              
                
df = pd.DataFrame(req_list, columns = columns)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
  estado mensajes codigoLocalidad descripcionLocalidad abreviaturaLocalidad departamentoLocalidad
0     OK     None               1              IQUIQUE                 None                     1
1     OK     None               2             IQUIQUE2            Something                     2
```

My Example Input File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:localidadesListarResponse xmlns:ns2="http://url.com/">
      <return>
      &lt;Respuesta&gt;&lt;Estado&gt;OK&lt;/Estado&gt;&lt;Mensajes&gt;&lt;/Mensajes&gt;&lt;ItemsLocalidades&gt;&lt;ItemLocalidad&gt;&lt;CodigoLocalidad&gt;1&lt;/CodigoLocalidad&gt;&lt;DescripcionLocalidad&gt;IQUIQUE&lt;/DescripcionLocalidad&gt;&lt;AbreviaturaLocalidad&gt;&lt;/AbreviaturaLocalidad&gt;&lt;DepartamentoLocalidad&gt;1&lt;/DepartamentoLocalidad&gt;&lt;/ItemLocalidad&gt;&lt;ItemLocalidad&gt;&lt;CodigoLocalidad&gt;2&lt;/CodigoLocalidad&gt;&lt;DescripcionLocalidad&gt;IQUIQUE2&lt;/DescripcionLocalidad&gt;&lt;AbreviaturaLocalidad&gt;Something&lt;/AbreviaturaLocalidad&gt;&lt;DepartamentoLocalidad&gt;2&lt;/DepartamentoLocalidad&gt;&lt;/ItemLocalidad&gt;&lt;/ItemsLocalidades&gt;&lt;/Respuesta&gt;
      </return>
    </ns2:localidadesListarResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```